# How do i change wifi password without a monitor (Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu-12.04

I have an ubuntu device that is wifi enabled, I plan to distribute it to clients that may not have a monitor.

What is the best way to modify the wifi password of such a device ?

Comment: Is there an ethernet port? If so, plug it into the hard-wired network while you use remote login to change the WiFi settings.

Comment: There is an ethernet port but i cannot afford to go change the password manually when my client needs to.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is a Windows / Linux machine with a monitor available on the same network, you can login into this ubuntu device using VNC and get a GUI or SSH it if you prefer the command line.

Of course this wont if your wifi password has already changed and your ubuntu device is not able to connect to the network.

Comment: yes that would be the condition. It potentially might happen.